# C # memory management and performance

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, c#-4.0

The criteria is simple. I am developing a winform application using C# 4.0 and have a win form having a grid view. On the load event, I retrieve data from database and then assign the datasource to the gridview. I have used BackGroundWorker object for database retrieval. This is nice. My GUI is responsive. The records are more than about 10 lac. So i fill my datatable using background worker and then assign the datatable to gridview. The problem is, my system gets slower. When i minimize mdi form of my application and try to do other things like opening internet browser and stuff, my  pc gets slower. I have core i3 2ith 2GB RAM. A grid having 10 lac records makes my system slow. How to manage memory in this case? Here is the code:

BackgroundWorker bWorker;
        DataTable dt;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        bWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
        bWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
        bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    void m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        //progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        //label1.Text  = "Data Loaded Successfully!";
        this.Hide();
        this.Show();
    }

    void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = getDataTable();
        //bWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
    void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you play with the main UI thread
        //progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    private DataTable getDataTable()
    {
        string conStr = ConString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select *from testtable",con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please guide me how to manage memory so that system should not get slower. If i dispose datatable after assigning it to grid, would that help?

I am actually a beginner. And want a complete guidance about memory management. Application should be fast. Thanx

Comment: What does "10 lac records" mean?

Comment: 1 million rows of a database table

Comment: Please, paste the code of getDataTable()

Comment: ok The post is updated and getDatatble method is there

Comment: "A grid having 10 lac records..." ... is going to be unusable for the user anyway. Implement some form of filtering and/or paging.

Comment: "lac" - According to [this post](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/925253-deletion-5-lac-records-table.html) it's an Indian term. Never heard of it before.

Comment: Also (and this is not a solution to your problem) the `getDataTable` method displays a message box in case of errors. This shouldn't be. First, the method has nothing to do with the "view", so it shouldn't display anything, also you should not use `try catch` blocks within background workers, but handle the errors in `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your problem is that your DataGridView creates a row for each row in the result set. You should read about what the [virtual display mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd28yf6d.aspx) is, the [VirtualMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx) and [how to implement it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can't expect to load a million rows of data into a GUI control and expect everything to behave well, can you?

The problem is here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select *from testtable",con);
```

There's no way you should be `SELECT`ing the entire table.  You'll want to `LIMIT` your query to only those rows that the GUI can reasonably display.  Shooting completely in the dark, I'd say somewhere on the order of a thousand rows at maximum.

Comment: Well but what if user want to filter some data from the entire data? He only would be able to filter from a thousand rows not from the entire million of records.

Comment: @user2109843 Filter? Ummmmm that's what SQL is for! Have you ever heard of `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

My assumation is you try to load all those rocords one time in getDataTable. Why not load by demand? I.e., only load the first level load. If all those are first level, you can separate into multi pages whose size may be a screen width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataGrid control with setting all appropriate select, insert, update, delete statements, add paging rules and this will also to the trick. The grid will not load all the records in once, but instead, it will use the clever internal functionality to select from the db and display only the appropriate data.
Hope this helps also.